Error: Framework OpenGLES not found with VS Mac project
I have a VS Mac project using OpenTK 4.8.2.
Visual Studio Mac is 17.6.11, MacBookPro M1 is MacOS 14.4.1.
When building I receive this error:
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.macOS.Sdk/13.3.7142/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(3,3): 
Error: clang++ exited with code 1:
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lSystem.Globalization.Native', '-lSystem.IO.Compression.Native', '-lSystem.Native', '-lSystem.Net.Security.Native', '-lSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple', '-lSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl', '-lclrgc', '-lclrjit', '-lcompression', '-lcoreclr', '-lhostfxr', '-lhostpolicy', '-lmscordaccore', '-lmscordbi'
ld: framework 'OpenGLES' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (QvxMac)

From build output:
  Tool xcrun execution started with arguments: clang++ -Lobj/Debug/net7.0-macos/osx-x64/nativelibraries/Contents/MonoBundle -lSystem.Globalization.Native -lSystem.IO.Compression.Native -lSystem.Native -lSystem.Net.Security.Native -lSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple -lSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl -lclrgc -lclrjit -lcoreclr -lhostfxr -lhostpolicy -lmscordaccore -lmscordbi -lSystem.IO.Ports.Native -lSkiaSharp -lfreetype.6 -lopencv_world.3.2.0 -lNCSEcw -lpng14.14 -lsqlite3.0 -lraw -lgeotiff.5 -ljpeg.8 -ltiff.5 -lproj.25 -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.4.sdk -arch x86_64 /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.macOS.Runtime.osx-x64/13.3.7142/runtimes/osx-x64/native/libxamarin-dotnet-coreclr-debug.a -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lSystem.Globalization.Native -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lSystem.IO.Compression.Native -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lSystem.Native -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lSystem.Net.Security.Native -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lclrgc -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lclrjit -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lcoreclr -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lhostfxr -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lhostpolicy -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lmscordaccore -L/Users/thomasflemming/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.osx-x64/7.0.18/runtimes/osx-x64/native -lmscordbi /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.macOS.Runtime.osx-x64/13.3.7142/runtimes/osx-x64/native/Microsoft.macOS.registrar.coreclr.a -rpath @executable_path/../MonoBundle/ -framework Accelerate -framework Accounts -framework AdSupport -framework AppKit -framework ApplicationServices -framework AudioToolbox -framework AudioUnit -framework AVFoundation -framework AVKit -framework BusinessChat -framework CFNetwork -framework CloudKit -framework Contacts -framework ContactsUI -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreAudioKit -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreML -framework CoreServices -framework CoreSpotlight -framework CoreText -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreWLAN -framework EventKit -framework ExternalAccessory -framework FinderSync -framework Foundation -framework GameController -framework GameKit -framework GameplayKit -framework GLKit -framework ImageCaptureCore -framework ImageIO -framework Intents -framework IOSurface -framework iTunesLibrary -framework JavaScriptCore -framework LocalAuthentication -framework MapKit -framework MediaAccessibility -framework MediaLibrary -framework MediaPlayer -framework MediaToolbox -framework Metal -framework MetalKit -framework MetalPerformanceShaders -framework ModelIO -framework MultipeerConnectivity -framework NaturalLanguage -framework Network -framework NetworkExtension -framework NotificationCenter -framework OpenGL -framework OpenGLES 

I dont need OpenGLES. Can this framework be installed? Or can this be removed from xcrun parameters somehow?
